# How to set keytip on a ribbon?

Tags: vsto, add-in, ribbon

I set the value of my `keytip` attribute for a split button to be "*CKS*" but when I execute the add-on in Outlook 2010, I get the hint that it's accessible using "*Y7*". I'm guessing it's some default throw-in and an arbitrary number.

How do I force **my** choice of character combination to be the valid one on the ribbon?

Comment: It might be my ignorance but I assumed that one couldn't affect the choice of the keys needed to be pressed to access a component. I thought it was a feature of the ribbon to assign mnemonics on its own.

Comment: You can do it by using the `keytip` attribute in the customUI XML for the ribbon, but sometimes the Office programs decide to change it to Y1, Y2 etc, possibly because of a conflict with keytips for the built-in controls.

Comment: @OlleSjögren Can that behavior be overriden? (Without being a MS employee dedicated to Office development, that is.)

Comment: I don't think so. Compare your option _CKS_ to the built-in tabs and controls - anyone else beginning with _C_?

Comment: @OlleSjögren Actually not but I'm only working in Outlook. It's fully imaginable that other Office component is using it (or that MS wants that reserved for a certain usage or other reason). I wanted to start with "C" because I work at "CRM Konsulterna" and we're aiming at creating a product line accessible from the ribbon. It'd be neat to go "C+something" for each software piece we've released. Thanks!

Comment: For the record, I tried a `CKS` keytip in Excel 2010 (I don't have Outlook) on both a tab and a button, and they both work perfectly... :)

Comment: @OlleSjögren So I guess I was right - it's reserved for **something**. Well, good to know. Or do you mean that you have **overriden** the defaults of Office and enabled **your** own, customized "CKS" keytip?! If so, I'll be a bit worried why **I** can't. Also, put a short summary as an answer so you'll get some reputation. I know you want to... ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to use your own shortcuts by using the `keytip` attribute in the customUI XML for the ribbon, but sometimes the Office programs decide to change it to *Y1*, *Y2* etc., possibly because of a conflict with keytips for the built-in controls.

I don't have Outlook, but I tried the "*CKS*" keytip in Excel 2010, both on a tab and on a button, and it worked. Below is the XML used for the Excel ribbon:

```xml
<customUI onLoad="RibbonLoad" 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabTest" 
           label="Test" 
           keytip="CKS" >
        <group id="grpTest" 
               label="Group #1" >
          <button id="btn1" 
                  label="Button #1" 
                  size="large" 
                  keytip="CKS" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

Comment: It's +1 for the quality but I'll wait for a while before grading you up in case you're aiming at *Unsung here*, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue yesterday because there was another button with the same keytip. After changing the keytip, I could see my custom keytip properly