# Is there a way in Excel 2013 to specify a key or key combination (A keytip!) to be used to in conjunction with 'Alt' to select a ribbon tab in excel?

Tags: xml, excel, ribbon, excel-2013, vba

I have a workbook in use by a number of users.  For various reasons, some have more tabs in the ribbon when they open up my workbook than others, and when the workbook is opened and a user presses Alt, the corresponding key press associated with my custom ribbon tab will not always be the same.

[image]

Can I, for example, edit my XLSM file's XML so that the key pressed in conjunction with Alt will always be the same?  I would like a solution that will work in excel 2013 (although it would be a bonus if it also worked in 2010 and/or 2007)

I have not been very successful in my search for a solution BUT eventually found HALF an answer.  Apparently you add keytip="Z" or whatever in the customUI xml.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyCustomRibbonTab" label="TEAM" keytip="Z">         
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I was then able to find this ([How to set keytip on a ribbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774412)) retrospectively once I knew the correct terminology.

Trouble is it **doesn't appear to work in 2013.**

Comment: The standard way to do this is to precede the letter you want to be *hot* with an ampersand, as in `For&mula`, which would make Alt+M activate the Formula tab.

Comment: @KenWhite this seems to work in 2007, but it still doesn't appear as expected in 2013 unless I'm making a mistake... (I can't test 2010 at the moment)

Comment: Yeah, I don't have 2013 on this machine. I can't test it either, which is why I left a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks @KenWhite.  I think it must have been the particular key combinations that I'd tried because after changing the keytip to "la" instead of "LA" or "Z" it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turn's out that certain keys or key combinations just weren't going to work for me (I think).  I have no idea why and if anyone can provide a better explanation detailing what works/doesn't and why I'll mark it correct, BUT in the mean time, I got this to work by changing the `keytip` to `la` rather than `Z` or `LA`.  I'd be interested to know if this is just me...

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="MyCustomRibbonTab" label="TEAM" keytip="la">         
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```