# How to connect VSTO C# code to the ribbon and/or keyboard shortcuts

Tags: c#, vba, vsto

I have just started migrating to C# from VBA. I have about 100 VBA macros to convert, of which about 25 are either in a custom Ribbon entry or mapped to a keystroke, such as alt-P.

The only [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635463/i-have-a-vsto-application-as-an-add-in-to-ms-word-and-i-want-to-set-keyboard-sho) I can find says I need to retain some VBA code in order to do this.  Such a solution is totally unacceptable, I have wanted to dispense with VBA entirely. I can't help thinking this is like having to keep a bale of hay in the frunk of your Tesla to feed the horse.

Is there any better way?

Comment: Have you tried using 'KeyTips'? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774412/how-to-set-keytip-on-a-ribbon

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to get the keytip reference. As per the screenshot below, I want to reference the `Script Help` ribbon which is `Y2`.

[image: screenshot ribbon]

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> to show the control keytip control references for that ribbon. Now I want to reference the `Clean Data` button which is `Y7`.

[image: screenshot buttons]

Then you can use SendKeys to press those keytip references. By adding the following code.

```
    public void CallButtonFromAnotherRibbon()
    {
        try
        {
            SendKeys.Send("%");
            SendKeys.Send("Y");
            SendKeys.Send("2");
            SendKeys.Send("%");
            SendKeys.Send("Y");
            SendKeys.Send("7");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Unexpected Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

[Microsoft Documentation for KeyTips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.keytip.aspx)

[Microsoft Documentation for SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)